# Max Index of Array SAP HANA

Tags: arrays, hana-studio

Does anyone know how to get the Max Index of an array in SAP Hana (stored procedure).

How can I get the Maximum Index via a single call for populated SAP Hana String array.
I am looking for something similar to:

```
MaxIdx := stringarray.RowCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum Index with the function

```
CARDINALITY
```

For your example:

```
MaxIdx := CARDINALITY(:stringarray);
```

Source: http://help.sap.com/hana/sap_hana_sql_script_reference_en.pdf